# Bucket policies allow upload certain file types

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I have build `minio` server to store file with custom policy by `mc`. I have policy file below.

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*.jpg"
      ],
      "Sid": "Statement1"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
      ],
      "Sid": "Statement2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Statement `s3:GetObject` is working, but statement `s3:PutObject` is not working. I still upload everything on MinIO browser. So, what I have to do to upload only jpg images.

Comment: The above appears to be a Bucket Policy, is that correct? When you say that you can still upload everything, what credentials are you using and what permissions are associated with those credentials? For example, if you are using credentials from an IAM User and that user has permissions that already grant access to the bucket (eg `s3:*`), then you will have permission to upload anything. That might be okay because you "own" the system. The question is **how will users be uploading to that bucket and what credentials will they be using**? Do they have IAM credentials are are they using an app?

Comment: were you able to solve this? Just trying to know understand if something like this can be done with minio.

Comment: @properchels The problem is solved. When I setup minio with access key and secret key, it is also admin account and I think admin account has full policy, I try to create an user account with custom policy (json file above), this user account is limited poilicy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Allow only certain file types to be uploaded to my Amazon S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/)? It details a slightly more comprehensive method than the above. I.e., allowing a given extension, to give users permissions, and **disallowing** anything that's not that extension - to strip users with `*` permissions of the ability to upload anything else.

Without knowing what "not working" means, it's hard to debug. Can you provide the commands you're using, and any exceptions? Off the top of my head, here are debugging attempts I would try:

1. Is your file really `.jpg`, not `.JPG` or `.jpeg` or `.JPEG`?
2. Does changing `"arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*.jpg"` to `"arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"` work? If not, what about changing it to `"*"`?

---

On another note: I'd be skeptical of file type restrictions, because file types are only superficially enforced. Anyone who can rename a file can also upload it, because `.jpg` is just an extension, and guarantees nothing about the actual content. In the best case, enforcing the extension rule is a happy-path guard rail for users, but you can't actually rely on it to protect your system from anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have seen that link and followed that. 
In my case, I  have 2 issues. The first is restriction access public bucket and I used `mc` to set policy with statement 
```{
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
      ],
      "Sid": "Statement2"
    }```
and it's working, I can get public url but can not access Minio browser without login.

Comment: The second issue: in Minio browser, I just allow upload files which have `.jpg` extension. I have followed link that you shared above and I have my statement 2 like that 
```{
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*.jpg"
      ],
      "Sid": "Statement1"
    }```
but, I can upload everything in Minio browser (ex: pdf, exe,...)

Comment: I tried to use only statement `putObject` and not working. I still try statement PutObject with `"Effect": "Allow"` and `NotResource` but it has error `mc: <ERROR> Unable to setJSON policy `/tmp/policy.json` for `minio/my_bucket_name`. Policy has invalid resource.`

Comment: So your first issue, *"restriction access public bucket"*, is solved? Regarding *"I can upload everything in Minio browser (ex: pdf, exe,...)"*: this is likely because minio is *allowed* to write everything (by some policy, somewhere). To disallow non-jpg, you need to include the *disallow* policy from the link in my answer, which will override any more general *allow* policy somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is solved. When I setup minio with `access key` and `secret key`, it is also admin account and I think admin account has full policy, I try to create an user account with custom policy (json file above), this user account is limited poilicy.